# How to wrap text on PrimeNg's dropdown?

Tags: primeng, primeng-dropdowns

How do I wrap text that exceeds width on PrimeNg's dropdown field? I have tried using `.p-dropdown-label { word-wrap: break-word; }` but it did nothing. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to do it by adding the following rule to `styles.css`:

```css
.p-dropdown-item.p-ripple {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

You can also achieve the same result by using ng-deep on the component stylesheet, but keep in mind that ng-deep is deprecated.

```css
:host ::ng-deep .p-dropdown-item.p-ripple {
  white-space: normal;
}
```